# Rails 1.day.ago with argument as a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method which calls `ago` on a length of time, but the time should be able to be supplied as an argument, I've greatly simplified the method to the small part that matters, imagine that the argument was something like "day", or "month"

```
normalize_time(time)
  1.time.ago
end
```

How can I take the `time` argument, and execute it as a method on `1` to get a Time object back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.send(time).ago
```

If time comes from an untrusted source this would allow them to call any method they wanted on 1, so be careful

Comment: Except that send is being used so private methods are accessible. Having someone being able to do 1.send(:exit) on your server  might not be a lot of fun

Comment: Sure. There was a smiley though. Anyway, it was a rather bad joke I admit, I'll delete my comment.

Comment: it's okay because its actually called from private method which no user input can make it into. But I hear you on this concern for sure!

Comment: `raise ArgumentError unless allowed_periods.include?(time)`

Comment: To verify against all valid options: `raise ArgumentError unless %w(year mon month day mday wday yday hour min sec usec nsec).include?(unit_of_time)` (based on ActiveSupport source - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/63f8fabe4939ad59d597dfea441002ef5b16d2f4/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb#L295)

Answer (score 2):

Given the amount of choices is finite and small, have you considered using a case statement ?

```
case time
when :day
  1.day.ago
when :month
  1.month.ago
when :year
  1.year.ago
end
```

Comment: its not bad, but we'll have instances of `week`, `hour`, `minute` in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to pass in as `time`, you could do something like

```
1.send(time).ago
```

where `time` is something like `:day` etc.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to your answer (which certainly works), consider a library like [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic):

```
> require 'chronic'
> Chronic.parse('one day ago')
=> 2011-12-18 17:17:17 -0500
> Chronic.parse('one week ago')
=> 2011-12-12 17:17:21 -0500
> Chronic.parse('one month ago')
=> 2011-11-19 17:17:26 -0500
```

It probably does more than you actually want it to, and your solution is almost certainly faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can "trust", by simply doing a "case"…

```
case time
  when "day", "month"
    1.send(time).ago
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out right after I posted my question, the method `send()` seems to accomplish this rather well:

```
time = "day"
1.send(time).ago
```

Is this a good way to do this though?

Comment: This method is a reasonable way to achieve the result.  I was half way through typing it when your answer popped up.